# How can I create a new object with a field containing an object using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Typescript interface files and I am trying to create a simple minimal object of type Word with a WordForm object inside of it:

```
interface IWord {
    categoryId: number;
    createdBy: number;
    createdDate: any;
    groupId: number;
    ielts: boolean;
    lessonId: number;
    modifiedBy: number;
    modifiedDate: any;
    toefl: boolean;
    toeic: boolean;
    wordForms: IWordForm[];
    wordId: string;
}

interface IWordForm {
    createdBy: number;
    createdDate: any;
    definition: string;
    modifiedBy: number;
    modifiedDate: any;
    posId: number;
    primary: boolean;
    sample1: string;
    sample2: string;
    sample3: string;
    sample4: string;
    sample5: string;
    synoym: string;
    wordFormId: string;
    wordId: string;
}
```

This works okay:

```
            wos.word = <IWord>{
                categoryId: 1,
                lessonId: 1,
                groupId: 1,
                toefl: true
            }
```

But this give me an error:

```
            wos.word = <IWord>{
                categoryId: 1,
                lessonId: 1,
                groupId: 1,
                toefl: true,
                wordForm: <IWordForm>{
                   posId: 1
                }
            }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2352  Neither type '{ categoryId: number; lessonId: number;
>   groupId: number; toefl: boolean; wordForm: IWordForm; }' nor type
>   'IWord' is assignable to the other.   Property 'createdBy' is missing
>   in type '{ categoryId: number; lessonId: number; groupId: number;
>   toefl: boolean; wordForm: IWordForm;
>   }'.   admin   C:\H\admin\admin\app\routes\words.ts    76  Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Build: Neither type '{ categoryId: number; lessonId: number;
>   groupId: number; toefl: boolean; wordForm: IWordForm; }' nor type
>   'IWord' is assignable to the
>   other.    admin   C:\H\admin\admin\app\routes\words.ts    76

Can someone help and tell me how I can create a word object with a word form inside of it? Note that I know a lot of the parameters are missing in my assignment but by casting I think this should still work.

Comment: I think there is a typo "wordForms"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, the issue is that the interface has a wordForms property that takes a list of IWordForm, but you've provided a wordForm (singular) property, with a single word form, not a list. If you rename it and wrap your form in a list it should work:

```
wos.word = <IWord> {
    categoryId: 1,
    lessonId: 1,
    groupId: 1,
    toefl: true,
    wordForms: [{
        posId: 1
    }]
}
```

More generally, that's not how casting works. Casting won't help in cases like this; when you cast something you're promising that it has the type you provide, and that's fine if it's possible you're right (e.g. casting `string|number` to `number`), but TypeScript won't allow it if it *knows* you're definitely wrong (casting string to number), only if it's possible that you're right.

If you need to avoid this normally, you can force TypeScript to accept your correctness by casting to `any` first though, as below. Don't do this without good reason! (Stubs/mocks in tests are one of few good reasons I know):

```
wos.word = <IWord> <any> {
    categoryId: 1,
    lessonId: 1,
    groupId: 1,
    toefl: true,
    wordForm: <IWordForm>{
               posId: 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make each property "nullable" (with a question mark).

```
interface IWord {
    categoryId?: number;
    createdBy?: number;
    createdDate?: any;
    groupId?: number;
    ielts?: boolean;
    lessonId?: number;
    modifiedBy?: number;
    modifiedDate?: any;
    toefl?: boolean;
    toeic?: boolean;
    wordForms?: IWordForm[];
    wordId?: string;
}

interface IWordForm {
    createdBy?: number;
    createdDate?: any;
    definition?: string;
    modifiedBy?: number;
    modifiedDate?: any;
    posId?: number;
    primary?: boolean;
    sample1?: string;
    sample2?: string;
    sample3?: string;
    sample4?: string;
    sample5?: string;
    synoym?: string;
    wordFormId?: string;
    wordId?: string;
}
```

and wordForms is an array:

```
        wordForms: [{
           posId: 1
        }]
```

And..you probably don't need to cast types as you type.